# Creation of SDK in React Native and generate .aar file to integrate with native apps

Tags: react-native, android-studio, sdk, aar

The main objectve we are looking for is to create an SDK of a react native app by providing an .aar file and giving it it clients so our app can be intgrated in clients (Native) app with minimal configuration and without actual exchange of code from both the ends (excluding some custom files that act aas a ode of communication fbetween client and our app).

I have gone through below articles to achieve the same :-

https://medium.com/@gauravasrivastava89/sdk-development-with-react-native-part-1-46580839eae9

https://medium.com/@jyubinpatel/make-reactnative-module-as-a-library-and-how-its-used-into-android-native-application-35b13f65ac7c

while following the steps from the same iam not able to move past the step where i have to install maven-publish as i cannot find it or it may have been depricated.
[Image for Maven-publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Cf8.png)

i Need help regrading following 2 usecases.

1.Is there any easier way to generate .aar file without needing clients codebase or if needed with updated libraries and methods.

2.if there is any other approach to fullfill the objective of sharing sdk and including for clients without exposing the code it would be very helpful.